# Package manager for android terminal

Tags: terminal

Just wanted to ask whether there was a package manager which could be installed on android terminal like homebrew cask, macports (macOS).
PS Just wanted to install small application like wget and curl.

Comment: Try [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux)'s `apt install`, or see if those binaries are available in any BusyBox app from Play Store.

Answer (score 4):

No.

There are some projects to port Debian `apt` but they were unusably unstable last I tested.

**2018 update**

Termux is reliable and can install [select packages](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/tree/master/packages) (I use `ssh`/`rsync`), more packages are available in [termux-ubuntu](https://github.com/Neo-Oli/termux-ubuntu) etc, but many won't work or require workarounds due to the unusual environment.

Comment: +1 for that. Good answer.